# Laravel: How can I keep the orderBy when I convert to json?

Tags: json, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am generating a query that returns results from a camp. I am sending it to another platform that digests this data as an array.

I am trying to return my `kickoffs` in order by score (highest to lowest).

Here is what the query looks like:

```
$camp = Camp::where('id', $camp_id)
    ->where('approved', 1)
    ->with(['athletes' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
        $q->with(['kickoffs' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
        $q->where('camp_id', $camp_id);
    }]);
    $q->with(['kickoff_results' => function ($q) use ($camp_id) {
        $q->where('camp_id', $camp_id);
        $q->orderBy('score', 'desc');
    }]);
    ...
})->first();

...
if ($camp) {
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $camp,
        ...
    ], 200);
}
```

In my other system this is how I am outputting it:

```
foreach ($context['camp']['data']['athletes'] as $athlete) {
    ...

    if (!empty($athlete['kickoff_results'])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When the result is finally rendered, it seems there is no order whatsoever.

Thank you for any suggestions!